# Как скопировать данные из csv в postgres

Tags: postgresql

Собственно, есть цсв, имена колонок не как в таблице. Как скопировать. Есть ems postgres и pgadmin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> есть цсв, имена колонок не как в таблице

поправить руками эту несчастную сотню символов

> Как скопировать

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2987451